# Calling free() sometimes causes program to crash

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, malloc, free

The code below ask the user to input 10 pairs of artist and titles which can be up to 30 characters long. Everything seems to work fine with allocating the space and printing the data back out. The problem only occurs when I try to free the memory at then end and then only if one of the elements is 4 or more characters long. I suspect I am not allocating the memory correctly but I just can't see it.

```
// Songs.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.
//
// Experimenting with pointers, structures and dynamic allocation of memory
//
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif


#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

struct songInfo
{
    char* pArtist;      // char pointer for Artist data
    char* pTitle;       // char pointer for Title data
};

// function prototype declarations
void getSongInfo(struct songInfo *songData, char *Artist, char *Title);
void printSongInfo(songInfo *songData);


int main()
{
    struct  songInfo songData[10];      // setup array of 10 elements of the structure SongInfo
    char    sArtist[31];
    char    sTitle[31];

    // prompt user for the artist and title 10 times once for each array element
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("Artist %i: ", i + 1);
        fgets(sArtist, 31, stdin);
        strtok(sArtist, "\n");          // trim out return character
        printf("Title  %i: ", i + 1);
        fgets(sTitle, 31, stdin);
        strtok(sTitle, "\n");           // trim out return character
        getSongInfo(&songData[i], sArtist, sTitle); // allocates the memory and stores the data into the pointer location
    }

    printSongInfo(songData);    // printout the song data stored in the array

    // free up the allocated memory space
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        free(songData[i].pArtist);
        free(songData[i].pTitle);
}
    return 0;
}

void getSongInfo(struct songInfo *songData, char *Artist, char *Title) {
    songData->pArtist = (char*)malloc(sizeof(Artist) + 1);  // Allocate enough memory to hold the string and the null terminator
    songData->pTitle = (char*)malloc(sizeof(Title) + 1);
    strcpy(songData->pArtist, Artist);                                  // Copy the data into the allocated memory location
    strcpy(songData->pTitle, Title);
}

void printSongInfo(songInfo *songData) {
    printf("\n%-35s %-35s\n", "Artist", "Title");
    printf("%-35s %-35s\n", "-----------------------------------", "-----------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {      // iterate through the array of elements
        printf("%-35s %-35s\n", songData[i].pArtist, songData[i].pTitle);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's better that you can't see it. *Remove all malloc/free/new/delete/ stuff* and use smart pointers and STL. CRT warnings are there for a good reason.

Comment: Side note - your code is pure C if you remove `#include <iostream>`. If you want to stay with C, that's fine, but in C++ *all* of your code would be much simpler by using `std::string` and `iostream` library.

Comment: The code is just for some general testing, at this point it I am not trying to do any validation of input or worrying about some details. It was primarily for experimenting with memory allocation, de-allocation and structures. I don't program in C, C++, C#. My experience is more in DBL/Dibol, COBOL, RPG. Done some Java and Pascal as well in College courses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It's not `free()` call that is invalid, it's `malloc`.

If you'd print out `sizeof(Artist) + 1`, you'd likely get either `5` or `9` (depending on your computer architecture). And the same for `Title`. You check the size of pointer on your machine, which is constant, not the size of array you received.

Undefined Behvaiour means your code may do anything, including "working for now, but will break later at a correct place". You invoke UB by calling `strcpy`, which tries to copy data into buffer too short to contain the whole string.

You have to pass the size of array to function or calculate it using `strlen` inside function (and pray that the string is actually null-terminated).

```
void getSongInfo(struct songInfo *songData, char *Artist, char *Title) {
    songData->pArtist = (char*)malloc(strlen(Artist) + 1);  // Allocate enough memory to hold the string and the null terminator
    songData->pTitle = (char*)malloc(strlen(Title) + 1);
    strcpy(songData->pArtist, Artist);                                  // Copy the data into the allocated memory location
    strcpy(songData->pTitle, Title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me solve the issue. I have it working now and when I trace it in debug I can see the appropriate size being allocated now.

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::char_traits::length](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/length) or [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/). Instead of length of the array, `sizeof(Artist)` gives you how many bytes a `char *` pointer occupies.

```cpp
songData->pArtist =
    (char*)malloc(std::char_traits<char>::length(Artist) +
                  1);  // Allocate enough memory to hold the string and the null terminator
songData->pTitle =
    (char*)malloc(std::char_traits<char>::length(Title) +
                  1);  // Allocate enough memory to hold the string and the null terminator
```

Just a side note: using `std::string` and smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` would save you lots of troubles dealing with memory issues. Overall, using modern `c++` will help you write safer code more efficiently.